# Can I access the DATA from a required script in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to access the text after `__END__` in a ruby file other than the "main" script?

For example:

```
# b.rb
B_DATA = DATA.read
__END__
bbb
```

.

```
# a.rb
require 'b'
A_DATA = DATA.read
puts 'A_DATA: ' + A_DATA
puts 'B_DATA: ' + B_DATA
__END__
aaa
```

.

```
C:\Temp>ruby a.rb
A_DATA:
B_DATA: aaa
```

Is there any way to get at the "bbb" from b.rb?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `DATA` global constant is set when the "main" script is loaded. A few things that might help:

You *can* at least get `A_DATA` to be correct. Just reverse the order of the first two operations in `a.rb`:

```
# a.rb
A_DATA = DATA.read
require 'b'
...
```

You can get the `B_DATA` to be correct if you go through a bit of rigamarole:

```
# load_data_regardless_of_main_script.rb
module LoadDataRegardlessOfMainScript
  def self.from(file)
    # the performance of this function could be
    # greatly improved by using a StringIO buffer
    # and only appending to it after seeing __END__.
    File.read(file).sub(/\A.*\n__END__\n/m, '')
  end
end

# b.rb:
require 'load_data_regardless_of_main_script'
B_DATA = LoadDataRegardlessOfMainScript.from(__FILE__)
```

Comment: This expression also works for getting the stuff after __END__: s =~ /^__END__\n/ && $'

Comment: `File.read(__FILE__)...` should be `File.read(file)...` in the `from` method.

Answer (score 4):

Implementing @James's suggestion to use StringIO:

```
require 'stringio'
module LoadDataRegardlessOfMainScript
  def self.from(filename)
    data = StringIO.new
    File.open(filename) do |f|
      begin
        line = f.gets
      end until line.match(/^__END__$/)
      while line = f.gets
        data << line 
      end
    end
    data.rewind
    data
  end
end
```

Then b.rb becomes

```
require 'load_data_regardless_of_main_script'
B_DATA = LoadDataRegardlessOfMainScript.from(__FILE__).read
```

Comment: More like +1 for a great example

Comment: +1 for a great example as well! One change I made is to use `until line.nil? or line.match(/^__END__$/)`. That way the method can be run against any ruby file without knowing in advance if it has a `DATA` section.